# Connect to tor with java - TorLib

Tags: java, network-programming

I know there is TorLib library where you can connect with tor through java.
This is the url:
http://web.mit.edu/foley/www/TinFoil/src/tinfoil/TorLib.java
. Although when i run i get that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TorLib (wrong name: tinfoil/TorLib)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: TorLib.  Program will exit.
```

if my mistake is a missing library where i can find it and how to install it?

If its not a missing library then what is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **IDE** look for the class in the **ClassPath** : `tinfoil/TorLib`, so you need to change the package name to fix your problem.